# changing opacity using tooltip.style("opacity","0") vs tooltip.style.opacity = 0

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to add a fade in and fade out effect on a tooltip so I added the following properties to CSS:

```
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 14px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  border-radius:10%;
```

in the javascript file I initialized using

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");
tooltip.style("opacity","0");
```

then i have

```
.on("mousemove", function(d){
tooltip.style.opacity = 1;
}
```

and finally

```
.on("mouseout", function(d){ tooltip.style.opacity = 0;})
```

now for some reason the above just doesn't change the opacity of the tooltip at all.( i can't see anything changing in styles or computed section)

I later tried using `tooltip.style("opacity","0")` instead of `tooltip.style.opacity = 0` and

`tooltip.style("opacity","1")` instead of `tooltip.style.opacity = 1` and now i can see that the opacity is added inline to the tooltip and it works as expected. 
I am currently learning javascript and i don't know why this is happening and i can't find anything helpful when googling. it would be great if someone could help me understand why one works while the other seems to have no effect.

the code is on [github](https://github.com/TamerMograbi/anime_vis_heroku)

and it is deployed on [heroku](https://anime-visual.herokuapp.com/)

sharing in case it might help

Comment: Please share where you define `tooltip`.

Comment: Interesting. Reading [the MDN article on `style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style), it references [a list of _common_ CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference), but the link text reads "a list of the CSS properties accessible via style" (note _accessible_). This would suggest to me that not _all_ CSS properties are accessible via `style`. Checking the list, sure enough, `opacity` is not on it. However, this is just an assumption at this point, the article isn't entirely clear to me here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, maybe you could try if it works with array-notation, i.e. `tooltip.style["opacity"] = 1`? Also, another option seems to be [`setProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty).

Comment: @domsson, it's interesting that opacity wasn't on that lst of CSS properties accessible via style, that might be the reason it isn't working. i did try tooltip.style["opacity"] = 1 but that also has no effect

Comment: I also can't seem to find any documentation regarding style as in tooltip.style("opacity","0"). this style is a method, and it's not the same as the property tooltip.style (i think). @domsson  btw, setProperty also works! thank you for pointing it out, it's very helpful as I had no idea you can iterate over the ccsRules in a css file and use setProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property (e.g. `element.style.opacity`) is part of the native [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)  interface.

However, you're not using native methods to select the element - you're using D3. Per the [documentation](https://www.d3indepth.com/selections/), `d3.select()` returns a d3 object with its own methods and properties, **not** an `HTMLElement`.

One of those D3-specific methods is `.style()`.

> **D3 - Selections**
>
> Once we’ve made a selection we can modify the elements in it using the following functions:
>
> ```
> Name      Behaviour             Example
> ---       ---                   ---
> .style    Update the style      d3.selectAll('circle').style('fill', 'red')
> .attr     Update an attribute   d3.selectAll('rect').attr('width', 10)
> ```